# MLFlow project run fails during conda env creation

Tags: conda, mlflow

I am trying to get mlflow mlproject working.

When i run the mlflow run with repo name

```
mlflow run  git@gitlabe2.xx.yy.zz:name/mlflow-example.git
```

The execution fails with the below error

```
File "/home/example/miniconda/envs/mlflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/projects/__init__.py", line 265, in run
use_conda=use_conda, storage_dir=storage_dir, synchronous=synchronous, run_id=run_id)
File "/home/example/miniconda/envs/mlflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/projects/__init__.py", line 144, in _run
conda_env_name = _get_or_create_conda_env(project.conda_env_path)
File "/home/example/miniconda/envs/mlflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/projects/__init__.py", line 144, in _run
conda_env_name = _get_or_create_conda_env(project.conda_env_path)
File "/home/example/miniconda/envs/mlflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/projects/__init__.py", line 498, in _get_or_create_conda_env
conda_env_path], stream_output=True)
File "/home/example/miniconda/envs/mlflow/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mlflow/utils/process.py", line 38, in exec_cmd
raise ShellCommandException("Non-zero exitcode: %s" % (exit_code))
```

Any pointers on where I should look ?

The suspect the conda.yaml file has some issues especially the conda env name.
I have different names for the environment where the project is created and where the project is being run. Does it matter ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem as suspected was with the conda yaml file.  Creating the yaml file of the project with --no-builds option solved the issue

```
conda env export --no-builds > conda.yaml
```

Thanks

Comment: where exactly you add this? I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and it was due to the encoding of the conda.yaml when I created it from my environment. The below are based on my observations on windows 10 in vscode.

**This doesn't work:**

`conda env export > conda.yaml`
This results in an encoding of `UTF-16 LE` which will cause conda to fail when creating the environment.

**Use this instead:**

`conda env export -f conda.yaml`
This results in an encoding of `UTF-8` which conda can use to create an environment.

Answer (score 0):

One of the reasons for getting this error may be low disk space. If you are out of disk space, consider freeing some memory and then go to folder `~/anaconda/envs` and delete the folder under this directory. The folder name starts with conda. This folder contains some libraries used during the conda environment creation, but because of the low memory it stopped and did not install all libraries needed. After freeing some memory you can run it again.